# Why cant I append a jquery object to a ul element

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jquery to select all the li elements and then appending them to another ul with an #id names second. The problem is that its not appending. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

If anyone could help me I would really appreciate it.

```
<ul>
    <li> Test </li>
    <li id="test"> Test 2 </li>
</ul>
<ul id="second"></ul>

<script>
    li.each(function () {
        $("#second").append($(this));
    })
</script>
```

Comment: You need to wrap your jQuery code in a document ready handler, `$(function() { /* code here */ });`. Then you should use a valid selector in a jQuery object, such as `$('li')`, not just `li`.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There are dozens of examples on the Internet how to do this...

Comment: Please provide  more complete example. In your html sample, I do not see any element with id `second`.

Comment: look at the errors thrown in console... `li` is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to iterate over each `li` element. You can `append` with them in the selector

```js
 $("#second").append($('#first li'));
```

```css
#second {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="first">

  <li>Test</li>
  <li id="test">Test 2</li>
</ul>

<ul id="second">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your jQuery code in a document ready handler, `$(function() { /* code here */ });`. Then you should use a valid selector in a jQuery object, such as `$('li')`, not just `li`. Also, you don't need to loop through all the `li` elements, as you can append them together in a single operation. Try this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#second').append('li');
    });
</script>
```